# Top of scrollable element is hidden

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project including a table with scrollable cells.  This may not look like the most elegant way to use a table, but this is what works for my use case.  Unfortunately, I the top portion of my cell content remains hidden, I cannot scroll to it...

Here's a very small sample from the project (a single cell of a much larger table):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div>
                    SAMPLE CONTENT1. SAMPLE CONTENT2. SAMPLE CONTENT3. SAMPLE CONTENT4. SAMPLE CONTENT5.
                    SAMPLE CONTENT6. SAMPLE CONTENT7. SAMPLE CONTENT8. SAMPLE CONTENT9. SAMPLE CONTENT10.
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
th{
    border: black 5px solid;
}

th div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
}
```

Why can't I see the top few lines of my scrollable text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove align-items:center

```css
th{
    border: black 5px solid;
}

th div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div>
                    SAMPLE CONTENT1. SAMPLE CONTENT2. SAMPLE CONTENT3. SAMPLE CONTENT4. SAMPLE CONTENT5.
                    SAMPLE CONTENT6. SAMPLE CONTENT7. SAMPLE CONTENT8. SAMPLE CONTENT9. SAMPLE CONTENT10.
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Simple fix!  Thank you so much!